# What about the server uptime when using CGI-binaries?

Tags: ajax, perl, xmlhttprequest, server, cgi

I have a need to convert some of my perl CGI-scripts to binaries.
But when I have a script of 100kb converted into binary it becomes about 2-3Mb. This is understood why, as compiler has to pack inside all the needed tools to execute the script.
The question is about the time of pages loading on the server, when they are binary. Say, if I have a binary perl-script "script", that answers on ajax requests and that binary weights about 3mb, will it reflect on AJAX requests? If, say, some users have low connection, will they wait for ages until all these 3Mb will be transferred? Or, the server WON'T send all the 3mb to a user, but just an answer (short XML/JSON whatsoever)?

Another case is when I have HTML page, that is generated by this binary perl-script on the server. User addresses his browser to the script, that weights 3Mb and after he has to get an HTML page. Will the user wait again, until the whole script is been loaded (every single byte form those 3Mb), or just wait the time that is needed to load EXACTLY the HTML page (say, 70Kb), and the rest mass will be run on the server-side only and won't make the user to wait for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or, the server WON'T send all the 3mb to a user, but just an answer (short XML/JSON whatsoever)?

This.

The server executes the program. It sends the output of the program to the client.

There might be an impact on performance by bundling the script up (and it will probably be a negative one) but that has to do with how long it takes the server to run the program and nothing to do with how long it takes to send data back to the client over the network.

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping/Packaging a perl script into a binary can be useful for ease of transport or installation.  Some folks even use it as a (trivial) form of obfuscation.  But in the end, the act of "Unpacking" the binary into usable components at the beginning of every CGI call will actually slow you down.

If you wish to improve performance in a CGI situation, you should seriously consider techniques that make your script persistent to eliminate startup time.  mod_perl is an older solution to this problem.  More modern solutions include FCGI or wrapping your script into it's own mini web server.

Now if you are delivering the script to a customer and a [PHB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointy-Haired_Boss) *requires* wrapping for obfuscation purposes, then be comforted that the startup performance hit only occurs once if you write your script to be persistent.